# I'm trying to write a array bytes in a file but i can not. (I can create this file in FileSystem, and the conection is working). Any help is grateful

Tags: java, file, hadoop, filesystems, hdfs

The main errors are:

1. File `/test/1.txt` could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 `datanode(s)` running and 1 `node(s)` are excluded in this operation.
2. Exception in `createBlockOutputStream`.

Also i try to write a String and its imposible.

```
public void establece_connexion() {

        try {

            //System.setProperty("HADOOP_USER_NAME", "hduser"); //por si acaso lo necesitamos.
            //UserGroupInformation ugi = UserGroupInformation.createRemoteUser(usuario_remoto);
            Configuration conf = new Configuration();
            conf.set("hadoop.job.ugi", usuario_remoto);
            conf.set("fs.defaultFS", namenode); // namenode ="hdfs://" + ip + ":" + puerto
            hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(conf);
            //hdfsFileSystem = FileSystem.get(new URI(namenode), new Configuration());
            System.out.println("Se declara HDFS como sistema de archivos subyacente");

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("Error en la conexión");

        }
    }
  public void write() {

        int numero = 1;

        while (numero <= get_numero_ficheros_totales()-1) {


            try {

                System.out.println("Voy a empezar a escribir DE NUEVO");

                //Path workingDir = hdfsFileSystem.getWorkingDirectory();
                //Path archivo = new Path(hdfsFileSystem.getWorkingDirectory() + "/" + hdfsPath + "/" + numero + ".txt"); //creamos el nuevo fichero//
                Path archivo = new Path(namenode + "//test//" + numero + ".txt");

                System.out.println("ESTOY AQUI YA ");

                //Hay una comprobacion de si si existe el ficehro que yo he creado

                if (hdfsFileSystem.exists(archivo)) {

                    System.out.println("El fichero " + numero + "  ya existe, no lo voy a crear de nuevo");

                } else { //una vez que comprobamos que no existe el archivo, o ya esta borrado el archivo lo creamos o lo cremos de nuevo.
                    System.out.println("no existe el archivo" + numero);

                    FSDataOutputStream fsdata = hdfsFileSystem.create(archivo);


                    try {

                        byte[] arrayBytes = array_relleno();
                        //assert false;
                        fsdata.write(arrayBytes,0, arrayBytes.length); //esto sería sin escritura en zip//
                        //fsdata.writeUTF("hello");
                        //fsdata.writeUTF("hello");

                        System.out.println("Voy a empezar a escribir DE NUEVO");
                        System.out.println(fsdata);
                        fsdata.close();

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        System.out.println("No he podido escribir en el fichero");

                    }

                }



                } catch(IOException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            numero++;

        }
    }
```

Errors:

```
Se declara HDFS como sistema de archivos subyacente
Voy a empezar a escribir DE NUEVO
ESTOY AQUI YA 
no existe el archivo1
Voy a empezar a escribir DE NUEVO
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.client.HdfsDataOutputStream@6ccdb29f
2019-08-26 09:45:21,849 INFO  [Thread-4] hdfs.DFSClient (DFSOutputStream.java:createBlockOutputStream(1368)) - Exception in createBlockOutputStream
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: no further information
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:531)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1309)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1262)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
2019-08-26 09:45:21,854 INFO  [Thread-4] hdfs.DFSClient (DFSOutputStream.java:nextBlockOutputStream(1265)) - Abandoning BP-328389572-127.0.1.1-1566466459521:blk_1073742162_1338
2019-08-26 09:45:21,916 INFO  [Thread-4] hdfs.DFSClient (DFSOutputStream.java:nextBlockOutputStream(1269)) - Excluding datanode DatanodeInfoWithStorage[127.0.0.1:50010,DS-9a5d1ada-fad9-4916-82c3-3c7125a6907a,DISK]
2019-08-26 09:45:21,925 WARN  [Thread-4] hdfs.DFSClient (DFSOutputStream.java:run(557)) - DataStreamer Exception
org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RemoteException(java.io.IOException): File /test/1.txt could only be replicated to 0 nodes instead of minReplication (=1).  There are 1 datanode(s) running and 1 node(s) are excluded in this operation.
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.blockmanagement.BlockManager.chooseTarget4NewBlock(BlockManager.java:1576)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getNewBlockTargets(FSNamesystem.java:3107)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.FSNamesystem.getAdditionalBlock(FSNamesystem.java:3031)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.namenode.NameNodeRpcServer.addBlock(NameNodeRpcServer.java:725)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolServerSideTranslatorPB.java:492)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocol.proto.ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos$ClientNamenodeProtocol$2.callBlockingMethod(ClientNamenodeProtocolProtos.java)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Server$ProtoBufRpcInvoker.call(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:616)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Server.call(RPC.java:982)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2049)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler$1.run(Server.java:2045)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Server$Handler.run(Server.java:2045)

    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1475)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1412)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.ProtobufRpcEngine$Invoker.invoke(ProtobufRpcEngine.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.protocolPB.ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.addBlock(ClientNamenodeProtocolTranslatorPB.java:418)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invokeMethod(RetryInvocationHandler.java:191)
    at org.apache.hadoop.io.retry.RetryInvocationHandler.invoke(RetryInvocationHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy11.addBlock(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.locateFollowingBlock(DFSOutputStream.java:1455)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1251)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:448)
No he podido escribir en el fichero
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a answer, the problem is solved.
I've been trying to connect to a cluster to another linux (ubuntu 18.10) computer where hadoop was installed. i acess whit mi windows computer (all in the same network).
In file core-site.xml I have changed "localhost" to 0.0.0.0 for access from mi other machine (windows). there was the problem. i change the ip to 192.168.3.37 (ip where are you dating) and it`s working fine. and then reestart namenode and datanode.

```
old-dated---------------:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://0.0.0.0:8020</value>
        <description>Nombre del filesystem por defecto.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>

up-dated---------------:

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<configuration>
    <property>
        <name>fs.default.name</name>
        <value>hdfs://192.168.3.37:8020</value>
        <description>Nombre del filesystem por defecto.</description>
    </property>
</configuration>
```

At the beginning of the whole put localhost, but that could not remain to have to be accessible from another machine

Answer (score 0):

I think I was allowed to create the files but not write to them because I think I accessed the namenode but when I accessed the datanode I gave the error